# Why does the text-decoration: none not work inside p?

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

I have the following HTML and CSS snippet and I want the "!" not to be underlined, but it is. What am I doing wrong?

```css
p {
  color:red; 
  text-decoration: 
    underline; 
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

span.none {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="p">Click the thumb<span class="none">!</span></p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `display:inline-block;` to `span.none class`

```css
p {
  color:red; 
  text-decoration: 
    underline; 
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

span.none {
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p class="p">Click the thumb<span class="none">!</span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works now. Can you explain why that is necessary, i.e. what it does exactly?

Answer (score 11):

> Why does the text-decoration: none not work inside p?

**tldr;** When text decorations are propogated to their descendant elements they can't be undone, however in certain situations they **don't get propogated** to their descendants.

This exact example is documented on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration): (emphasis mine)

> Text decorations draw across descendant elements. This means that it
>   is not possible to disable on a descendant a text decoration that is
>   specified on one of its ancestors.
>
> **For example,** in the markup:
>
> `<p>This text has <em>some emphasized words</em> in it.</p>`,
>
> the style rule `p { text-decoration: underline; }` would cause the entire paragraph to be
>   underlined. The style rule `em { text-decoration: none; }` would not
>   cause any change; the entire paragraph would still be underlined.

**However**, sometimes text decorations **don't propagate** to their descendant elements - see the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/text.html#lining-striking-props) on 'text-decoration' property

> Note that text decorations are not propagated to floating and
>   absolutely positioned descendants, nor to the contents of atomic
>   inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables.

So this means that if the span element has

1) `display: inline-block`, or

2) is floated  or

3) is abolutely positioned then

**the text decorations are not propagated to it in the first place**. (which also means that text-`decoration: none;` isn't necessary)

```css
p {
  color:red; 
  text-decoration: 
    underline; 
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

span.none {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p class="p">Click the thumb<span class="none">!</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Fix, but ugly one, But do the trick. hope some one else come up with better answer.**

```css
p {
   color:red; 
   text-decoration: underline; 
   font-size: 1.2em;
}
p { 
   display: inline 
}
p.none {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="p">Click the thumb</p><p class="none">!</p>
```