# Prevent line-through of containing span

Tags: html, css

**TD;DR**

I am integrating a JS text editor, in my application. It permits to apply revisions to text, from various drafter (for the sake of curiosity, it is the Track Changes plugin of The New York Times, for CkEditor).

Just as a premise, and to keep it simple, it has two main CSS classes, `ice-ins` (for inserted text) and `ice-del` (for deleted text). `ice-ins` provides a green text color, `ice-del` provides a red text color and `line-through`; both of them operates on `span`s.

For some reasons, it is possible that (during writing) the two classes overlaps (they are both associated to the newly created span), and I have (as a workaround...) to let the `ice-ins` "win" on the other. I did like this:

```
if (node.className.indexOf("ice-del") != -1){
    console.log("I am writing as ice-del, which is wrong...");
    if (node.className.indexOf("ice-ins") != -1){
        console.log("Both ice-ins and ice-del are present: I delete ice-del");
        node.className = node.className.replace("ice-del", "");
        //I also want to remove the inherited line-through: DOESN'T WORK!
        node.style.textDecoration = "none";         
    }else{
        console.log("I just have ice-del class: I change it into ice-ins");
        node.className = node.className.replace("ice-del", "ice-ins");
        //I also want to remove the inherited line-through: DOESN'T WORK!
        node.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
}
```

The class substitution works well; by the way, I cannot "overwrite" the `line-trough` into `none`, because the `text-decoration` is inherited by a containing `span`. As a result, the text is inserted as green (which is correct) but striked-through (as an `ice-del`, which is wrong). Obviously my `node.style.textDecoration = "none";`  has no effect.

**/TL;DR**

So, how can I "overwrite" the `line-through` into `none`, inherited from a container `span`, through JS?
Can you suggest me a way to overcome it?

**Example:**

An actual representation of the problem is the following. Consider the red-squared content in the image:

[image]

The corresponding HTML is this:

```
<span class="ice-del ice-cts-1" data-cid="3" data-userid="utenzatecnica" data-username="utenzatecnica utenzatecnica" data-changedata="" data-time="1527492696670" title="Changed by utenzatecnica utenzatecnica 2 minutes ago">
    <span class="ice-ins  ice-cts-1" data-cid="3" data-userid="utenzatecnica" data-username="utenzatecnica utenzatecnica" data-changedata="" data-time="1527492696670" title="Changed by utenzatecnica utenzatecnica 2 minutes ago" style="text-decoration: none;">s</span>
    <span class="ice-ins  ice-cts-1" data-cid="3" data-userid="utenzatecnica" data-username="utenzatecnica utenzatecnica" data-changedata="" data-time="1527492696670" title="Changed by utenzatecnica utenzatecnica 2 minutes ago" style="text-decoration: none;">d</span>
    <span class="ice-ins  ice-cts-1" data-cid="3" data-userid="utenzatecnica" data-username="utenzatecnica utenzatecnica" data-changedata="" data-time="1527492696670" title="Changed by utenzatecnica utenzatecnica 2 minutes ago" style="text-decoration: none;">s</span>
    <span class="ice-ins  ice-cts-1" data-cid="3" data-userid="utenzatecnica" data-username="utenzatecnica utenzatecnica" data-changedata="" data-time="1527492696670" title="Changed by utenzatecnica utenzatecnica 2 minutes ago" style="text-decoration: none;">d</span>
    <span class="ice-ins  ice-cts-1" data-cid="3" data-userid="utenzatecnica" data-username="utenzatecnica utenzatecnica" data-changedata="" data-time="1527492696670" title="Changed by utenzatecnica utenzatecnica 2 minutes ago" style="text-decoration: none;">s</span>
INSEITO</span>
```

As you can see, each one of the newly inserted letters (s, d, s, d, s) is inserted as `ice-ins` (so, they're green), but `text-decoration:none` doesn't work, 'cause they are into an enclosing span with `ice-del`, that has `line-through`.

**Edit (and alternative solution):**

Another trick, that I end up with, is to move the child span element outside its parent:

```
node.parentNode.before(node);
```

So it will inherit the text-decoration no more.

Comment: So you have a span within a span? Some example html would help clarify the issue.

Comment: Changed `node.style.textDecoration = "none";` into `node.style.display = "inline-block";` after @Faibbus's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why `text-decoration: none;` does not reset the line-through, but you can use `display: inline-block;` :

```html
<style>
.blep {
  display: inline-block
}
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
</style>
<span class="strike">aaa<span class="blep">bbbbb</span>aaa</span>
```

Comment: Here's an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40829582/703717

Comment: Thanks @Danield. Your answer on the other thread is much more thorough. Have my upvote.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Somehow, I've missed that previous post.